# ffmpeg - How do I modify Channel Layout labels only on 8 separate mono audio tracks?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, davinci-resolve, metadata

I have a QuickTime .mov file which has 1 video track (ProRes 4444 XQ) and 8 mono audio tracks, which combined make up the 5.1 surround mix and a stereo mixdown. Per delivery requirements, I need to modify the audio track metadata to specify which channel each track represents - F, L, C, LFE, etc. - as visible in the attached screenshot from QuickTime Player.

[image: QuickTime Audio Details]

I have successfully modified this using a very old copy of QuickTime Pro 7 running on Windows, but I would like to use ffmpeg on a modern system. The .mov file is exported from DaVinci Resolve, but there doesn't seem to be any option for modifying these labels. With ffmpeg, I have attempted numerous combinations of -map and -filter_complex flags, but I have not been successful yet.

I know I can keep the 8 audio tracks separate using the following command, but with the channel layout for each still listed as 'mono':

`ffmpeg -i test_8mono.mov -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s24le -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:a:2 -map 0:a:3 -map 0:a:4 -map 0:a:5 -map 0:a:6 -map 0:a:7 ~/Desktop/test1.mov`

I know I can output only one of the 8 tracks using this command, and have the channel layout correctly listed as 'Left' in QuickTime Player:

`ffmpeg -i test_8mono.mov -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s24le -filter_complex "[0:a]channelmap='map=0':channel_layout=FL" ~/Desktop/test1.mov`

But I cannot figure what combination of these two will keep all 8 tracks separate (not multi-channel audio), but with channel_layout specified for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who needs the same thing as OP - MultitrackMaker for Mac does exactly this and is free.  Haven't tried it on Ventura, but it runs on Monterey.  https://www.mixagesoftware.com/index.html

Comment: Thank you! Completely solved my problem and it runs fine on macOS 13.3.1.